# getURL get stuck, need a wait function

Tags: r, wait, geturl

I am trying to use R to surf the web but I have a strange problem, lets say that I have a list named URLlist containing some URL. Here is my code

```
for (k in 1:length(URLlist)){
    temp = getURL(URLlist[k])
}
```

I don't know why but at some random URL, R blocks. It has nothing to do with the URL as it can work for an execution of the loop for but not for another one for the same URL. I think that the loop is going to fast and that the download of data doesn't follow. So I was thinking of making the code wait for 1 seconde before each new calling of getURL function, but I didn't find such a wait function.
Any idea please ? thank you !

Comment: I'm not sure that what you describe as going wrong is even possible. R is single threaded. Each time you call `getURL` R won't do anything else until it either completes or throws an error.

Comment: R hangs on me sometimes when I try to access HTTPS content behind an ill-configured proxy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

?Sys.sleep()

Description:

```
 Suspend execution of R expressions for a given number of seconds
```

Usage:

```
 Sys.sleep(time)
```

Arguments:

```
time: The time interval to suspend execution for, in seconds.
```

Whether or not this will solve your problem is another issue.

I would suggest looking at the XML package and using htmlParse() to surf the web with R since there are rarely instances where you want html being returned as text.